# Resume Docker push if interrupted?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerhub, docker-push

When pushing a large layer to Docker Hub, is there a setting to make to enable an interrupted image upload to be resumed on the next `docker push`?

```
docker push me/foo:latest

4e5786849edb: Pushing [=================>                                 ]  43.59GB/126.6GB
```

This way, if we were to interrupt the push right now, we can avoid having to upload all over again if we can resume from the point it was interrupted.

Comment: I'd highly recommend breaking this image into smaller layers.  My past experience has been that pushing and pulling layers larger than about 1 GB is prone to random failures.  Docker can keep track of the layers it has already pushed and pulled, so this will also help restarting interrupted operations.

Comment: @DavidMaze Good idea. This layer is probably from the Dockerfile line `COPY ./data/foo /data/` which is about same size as thatt large layer.